# yadcf cumulative filtering does not keep options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

I'm using the yadcf plugin (v0.9.3) to perform cumulative filtering on my datatables. The filtering is working fine, however I'm trying to fix the following behaviour :

- before I select anything in the primary select control, the number of options is 10
- when I select one of the 10 options, the filtering happens with no issue, but the 9 other options go away, and I need to "deselect the option" to find the complete list again.

here is my yacdf code :

```
yadcf.init(table, 
   [
      {
          column_number : 2,
                    filter_container_id: 'headergroupFltr',
                    filter_type: 'select',
                    filter_default_label: "Select Head Group",
                    filter_reset_button_text: false,
                    select_type: 'select2',
                    style_class:"js-example-basic-single js-states form-control"
      },
      {
         column_number : 3,
                    filter_container_id: 'subgroupFltr',
                    filter_type: 'select',
                    filter_default_label: "Select Sub Group",
                    filter_reset_button_text: false,
                    select_type: 'select2',
                    style_class:"js-example-basic-single js-states form-control"
      }
   ],
      {
         cumulative_filtering: true ,
         filter_match_mode: "exact" 
      }
);
```

I would like to keep all options available in the primary filter, even when I select one.
How can I acheive that ?

Comment: Hi, currently it's not really possible to use `cumulative_filtering` with `ajax data source` there is an open issue about it :|

Comment: Oh OK. Actually the filtering works well. Just that odd behaviour with the dropdowns.

Comment: Actually this is my mistake. This datatable does not use ajax. I build it on the fly using php. so no Ajax involved. I've edited my main question.

Comment: this is how cumulative works with server/ajax, see this issue https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/523